# moved to new fb:comments but old comments gone even with migrated="1"

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-c#-sdk, fbml, facebook-page

I have an FBML page tab that has the old fb:comments.
Now I'm trying to build an iframe to replace it.
So I added to my html code this lines:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>

 <fb:comments xid="271917093633" migrated="1">

 </fb:comments>
```

The result are that fb comments box appear, but all of the old comments are gone!

what should I do? 
does someone managed to migrate his old comments from fbml to iframe?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way to retained the comments if you are doing the migration explicitly.

try to specify the href, instead of xid next time when u create a comments box